# C++: std::vector::resize vs. "normal" allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, allocation

In the code example for `std::transform`, there is an example with code like this:

```
std::vector<int> foo;
std::vector<int> bar;

//add some elements to foo

bar.resize(foo.size());

//store elements transformed from foo's in bar
```

And I was wondering whether

```
std::vector<int> bar;    
bar.resize(foo.size());
```

was any different from

```
std::vector<int> bar(foo.size());
```

and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no difference. At least not in the way you show it (with no insertions into `foo` between the definition of `bar` and the call to `resize`).

Comment: What about the initial allocation of the internal array? Is that postponed to first insertion? Is that defined by the standard or an implementation-specific detail?

Comment: @odyss-jii Without checking the standard, but reading [this `std::vector` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (which says that e.g. the size-setting constructor is *"linear in count"*) I would say that the memory is allocated and initialized immediately.

Comment: So I guess that there is an implementation-specific initial array size in the default constructor? If so, then the implementation-specific, tiny, difference between the two snippets of the OP would be an extra delete and array allocation in the first case.

Comment: @odyss-jii No the default constructor creates a zero-sized vector (and doesn' need tot allocate any memory at all), any element access in a default-constructed vector is out of bounds.

Comment: Well, zero-sized vector yes, but that says nothing about the internal array (see `capacity` and `reserve` methods). I guess it depends on the allocator used and when it is invoked.

Answer (score 4):

No difference, except that the latter is a <sub><sup>tiny bit</sup></sub> more efficient and concise.

Comment: And a _tiny_ bit less clear whats going on... does the second one create a single item with the value of size or a sized vector? We all know but a less proficient user would find the first form clearer. I dont think its worth doing it the first way due to this though.